# Combining two SQL queries PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm quite stuck on the following issue. I have a series of tables:
[image: Image of the tables for convenience]

What I want to do is get all the information on a room, assuming that the amount of bookings don't exceed the room number available for that Room.

So to get my Room details my SQL is this:

```sql
  SELECT Rooms.RoomID as RoomID,
         RoomName, NumOfRooms, 
         MaxPeopleExistingBeds, 
         MaxExtraBeds, 
         MaxExtraPeople, 
         CostPerExtraPerson, 
         MaximumFreeChildren, 
         IncludeBreakfast, 
         MinRate 
    FROM Rooms, RoomDetails 
   WHERE Rooms.AccommodationID = :aid AND 
         Rooms.RoomID = RoomDetails.RoomID 
GROUP BY RoomName
```

Which upon return gets me a list of details for those rooms as follows:
[image]

I then use this query to get the number of bookings, and the ID of the room:

```sql
  SELECT Booking.RoomID, 
         count(Booking.RoomID) as Bookings  
    FROM Booking 
   WHERE ArriveDate >= :aDate AND 
         DepartDate <= :dDate AND 
         AccommodationID = :aid 
GROUP BY RoomID
```

I then combine both and feed the two arrays back in one array using this function:

```
public function get_availability($aid, $aDate, $dDate) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT Rooms.RoomID as RoomID, RoomName, NumOfRooms, MaxPeopleExistingBeds, MaxExtraBeds, MaxExtraPeople, CostPerExtraPerson, MaximumFreeChildren, IncludeBreakfast, MinRate FROM Rooms, RoomDetails WHERE Rooms.AccommodationID = :aid AND Rooms.RoomID = RoomDetails.RoomID GROUP BY RoomName');
        $stmt->bindValue(':aid', $aid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rooms = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare('SELECT Booking.RoomID, count(Booking.RoomID) as Bookings  FROM Booking WHERE ArriveDate >= :aDate AND DepartDate <= :dDate AND AccommodationID = :aid GROUP BY RoomID');
        $stmt2->bindValue(':aid', $aid);
        $stmt2->bindValue(':aDate', $aDate);
        $stmt2->bindValue(':dDate', $dDate);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $bookings = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $room = array($rooms, $bookings);

        return (!empty($room)) ? $room : false;
    }
```

The thing is, what I actually want to do is only return the room details where NumOfRooms is less than the number of Bookings.

So for instance where I have $bookings, if it tells me that for room ID 4, I have 3 bookings for a set period, and my NumOfRooms is 1. Then I know that I have no capacity that week to take any more bookings on. If however I have 1 booking and one capacity then that is still full. But if I have NumOfRooms of 2, and bookings amount to 1, I know I have room.

So basically if NumOfRooms > BookingCount then the room is available.

How can I amalgamate both queries and simplify my code to make this possible?

I.E to put it simply, how do I select all of the info from RoomDetails given an ArriveDate in Booking and a DepartDate and a RoomID, where NumOfRooms > count(Booking.RoomID) (Where it is within those dates and the room id is equal to the room id of Rooms).

Comment: offtopic: may I ask what was used to generate that SQL image?

Comment: Which bit sorry? The tables were made in Visio, the SQL is typed, the Array is from chrome's console. Used Puush to cut out the part of the screen I wanted (ctrl + shift + 4). That's all the images accounted for as I wasn't sure which you were referring to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by simply updating the SQL statement itself:

```sql
SELECT r.RoomID AS RoomID,
       RoomName,
       NumOfRooms,
       MaxPeopleExistingBeds,
       MaxExtraBeds,
       MaxExtraPeople,
       CostPerExtraPerson,
       MaximumFreeChildren,
       IncludeBreakfast,
       MinRate
FROM Rooms r
JOIN RoomDetails rd
    ON r.RoomID = rd.RoomID
JOIN (
    SELECT b.RoomID,
           AccommodationID,
           count(b.RoomID) AS Bookings
    FROM Booking b
    WHERE ArriveDate >= :aDate
      AND DepartDate <= :dDate
    GROUP BY RoomID
) t
    ON t.AccommodationID = r.AccommodationID
WHERE r.AccommodationID = :aid
    AND t.Bookings < NumOfRooms
GROUP BY RoomName
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The sql works without the third join, but the query in the third join works without all the other sql, but they don't work together. I think there is a flaw in the logic somewhere. The third inner join returns for example 4 RoomIDs, and their bookings. If there are no bookings in that period for that RoomID there won't be an entry for it. I find that if I change AND t.Bookings < NumOfRooms to <= or >= or > it displays all but it displays none with <. What I have are 9 entries of Rooms in the Rooms Table, with corresponding details in RoomDetails.

Comment: So if the Number of Rooms aren't greater than bookings they don't appear. The problem is in this period, even if there are no bookings, none show.

Comment: @DavidG Can you provide sample data on sqlfiddle?

Comment: @DavidG All of the Rooms in the sqlfiddle have capacity of 1. If that is the case, then you won't receive any results for `t.Bookings < NumOfRooms` as each Room has had atleast one booking. See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4983/2) query executing perfectly, when I change `NumOfRooms` to 3 for `RoomID = 4`

Comment: Oh I see!
Thanks for taking the time to help me out, I really appreciate it. If one of the rooms has a capacity of 1, but I pick dates where it isn't booked. Should I still expect it not to appear? (Haven't tested yet). Or would that work fine?

Thank you again :)

Comment: @DavidG I think it wouldn't show up. `COUNT` subquery will only return those rows which have some bookings in those ranges. You'd have to ask someone better than me for a query which'd return 0 if no booking is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can select out all of the booking counts per room for the desired date range as a subquery, and then `LEFT JOIN` that subquery against the list of your rooms filtered by your desired `AccommodationID` and the desired `NumOfRooms > BookingCount` criteria. The key here is in the join type used for this subquery, as an inner join would limit your results to only rooms that actually had bookings.

```
    SELECT Rooms.RoomID as RoomID,
           RoomName, NumOfRooms, 
           MaxPeopleExistingBeds, 
           MaxExtraBeds, 
           MaxExtraPeople, 
           CostPerExtraPerson, 
           MaximumFreeChildren, 
           IncludeBreakfast, 
           MinRate,
           BookingCount
      FROM Rooms
INNER JOIN RoomDetails on Rooms.RoomID = RoomDetails.RoomID
 LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT Booking.RoomID,
                      count(Booking.RoomID) as BookingCount
                 FROM Booking 
                WHERE ArriveDate >= :aDate AND 
                      DepartDate <= :dDate
             GROUP BY Booking.RoomID
           ) RoomBookings ON Rooms.RoomID = RoomBookings.RoomID
     WHERE Rooms.AccommodationID = :aid
       AND NumOfRooms > BookingCount
  GROUP BY RoomName
```