# In an SQL statement if nothing is found for a specific query, return an entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

This might seem a tad convoluted. But if you could have a quick read of the answer in this post:
[Combining two SQL queries PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883781/combining-two-sql-queries-pdo/22883976?noredirect=1#comment34923173_22883976)

Here is the Sample sqlfiddle that I am working with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4983/3

So what should happen here is that in my sql query:

```
SELECT r.RoomID AS RoomID,
       RoomName,
       NumOfRooms,
       MaxPeopleExistingBeds,
       MaxExtraBeds,
       MaxExtraPeople,
       CostPerExtraPerson,
       MaximumFreeChildren,
       IncludeBreakfast,
       MinRate
FROM Rooms r
JOIN RoomDetails rd
    ON r.RoomID = rd.RoomID
JOIN (
    SELECT b.RoomID,
           AccommodationID,
           count(b.RoomID) AS Bookings
    FROM Booking b
    WHERE ArriveDate >= :aDate
      AND DepartDate <= :dDate
    GROUP BY RoomID
) t
    ON t.AccommodationID = r.AccommodationID
WHERE r.AccommodationID = :aid
    AND t.Bookings < NumOfRooms
GROUP BY RoomName
```

At the moment it checks that bookings for each room aren't at capacity. Then displays them.
However if capacity is 1, and there are no bookings. It won't display the room.

Is it possible to reconstruct this statement in such a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you have joined your with `AccommodationID` and you have ignore the room id for `Booking` table which gives you the wrong count for the room booking you also need to join with room id and also you need to use `LEFT` join so if nothing returns from booking then it means your room is available ,when using join with `ON( t.AccommodationID =r.AccommodationID  AND r.RoomID = t.RoomID)` you will have null for bookings column (i.e no bookings were made to this room) so you need additional where condition to check if booking is null then return this room also because it is available to have guest

```
SELECT r.RoomID AS RoomID,
       RoomName,
       NumOfRooms,
       t.Bookings,
       MaxPeopleExistingBeds,
       MaxExtraBeds,
       MaxExtraPeople,
       CostPerExtraPerson,
       MaximumFreeChildren,
       IncludeBreakfast,
       MinRate
FROM Rooms r
LEFT JOIN RoomDetails rd
    ON r.RoomID = rd.RoomID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.RoomID,
           AccommodationID,
          COALESCE(count(b.RoomID),0) AS Bookings
    FROM Booking b
    WHERE ArriveDate >= '2014-02-26'
      AND DepartDate <= '2014-03-10'
    GROUP BY RoomID
) t
    ON( t.AccommodationID = r.AccommodationID 
       AND r.RoomID = t.RoomID)
WHERE r.AccommodationID = 1
   AND (t.Bookings < NumOfRooms OR t.Bookings IS NULL)
GROUP BY RoomName;
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4983/24)